# Menu is not showing on Mobile home page only in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site and on mobile menu is not showing on the homepage only, but the menu shows on other pages. How to make that menu visible on  the homepage too?

Comment: Might be a CSS style issue. Here is a sloution: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mobile-menu-not-visible-6/

Comment: please provide here your nav_manu code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in your active theme style.css file

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    #site-header.transparent-header {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

Comment: in style.css and also try  in customize css

Comment: I cannot see you style.css file. Can you this css in your header.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this at your custom css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
#site-header.transparent-header {
    position: fixed!important;
}
```

There's an element that having a -155px margin top value.